# An integer divisible by 8 and 15 must also be divisible by 24. Why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I have a question on the GRE that says "If an integer is divisible by both 8 and 15, then the integer must also be divisible by" and the choices are:

- 16
- 24
- 32
- 36
- 45

The answer is 24. I guess I could figure out that the first common multiple of 8 and 15 is 120 and plug in the numbers, but is there a more sophisticated way to do it? Something that follows from the properties of 8 and 15? It happens that 24 is the only number that goes into 120 but what if it wasn't? Is there a way to prove that 24 is the only one that works?

Comment: $\operatorname{lcm}(8,15)=120$. $\\\\24\mid 120$.

Comment: Think about the prime factors of each.

Comment: You've done it the right way.  Such a number must be divisible by $120$, and so by any factor of $120$.  If $60$ were on the list and $24$ was not, then the answer would be $60$.  You can't tell the answer without looking at the list.

Comment: @Randall, What about the prime factors? 8 is 2^3 and 15 is 3 and 5. So what does that tell me? The factor of 8, 2^3, times the first factor of 15, 3, equals 24. And the last factor of 15, 5, multiplied by 24 gives me 120. Is that it?

Comment: @saulpatz, But 60 is not divisible by 8.

Comment: "But 60 is not divisible by 8"  So what?  If $K$ is divisible by $a$ and $K$ is divisible by $b$ that doesn't mean $b$ is divisible by $a$.  $8= 2^3$ and $15 = 3*5$ and so the least common multiple is $120 = 2^3*3*5$ and so $2^3*3*5$ will divide the integer.  So $2^a*3^b*5^c$ will divide the integer if $0\le a \le 3; 0 \le b\le 1; 0\le c \le 1$.  And we have $24 = 2^3*3^1*5^0$ so that works.  And $60 = 2^2*3^1*5^1$ and that works. But $16=2^4*3^0*5^0$ and that does not work because $4 > 3$.

Comment: " It happens that 24 is the only number that goes into 120 but what if it wasn't? "  Then it wouldn't be the only answer.  Any number that goes into $120$ will be an answer.  But it is assume you can tell by looking that $24$ is the only one that goes into $120$.

Comment: "But 60 is not divisible by 8. "  and $24$ is not divisible by $15$.  That doesn't matter.  $1$ is not divisible by *anything* and it divides *all* integers.

Answer (score 7):

If $K$ is divisible by $a$ and $K$ is divisible by $b$ then $K$ is divisible by the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$.  ANd $K$ is divisible by all factors of the least common multiple of $a,b$.

The least common multiple of $8$ and $15$ is $8*15 = 120$.  And the factors of $120$ are $1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,               12,15,20,24,30,40,60,120$ and those will all divide the integer.  $24$ is the only one on the list.

Of course you don't have to create the entire list.  You just have to know $120$ divide the integer so anything that divides $120$ will also divide the integer.  And $24$ is the only thing on the list that divides $120$.

More detail:

$8 = 2^3$ and $15 = 3^15^1$ and the least common multiple of $8$ and $15$ is $2^33^15^1$ and that divides our integer.  So any number of the form $2^a3^b5^c$ where $a$ is at most $3$, $b$ is at most $1$ and $c$ is at most $1$ (and they *can* be $0$) will divide the integer.  But if any of the factors have larger powers or if the have primes other than $2,3,5$ we can't *know* they divide the integers.

$16 = 2^4$ that's out because $4 > 3$.

$24 = 2^3*3^1$ that's okay because $3 \le 3$ and $1 \le 1$.

$32 = 2^5$ that's out because $5 > 3$.

$36 = 2^2*3^2$ and that's out because $2 > 1$.

$45= 3^2*5^1$ and that's out because $2 > 1$.

Answer (score 5):

If this integer is divisible by $8$ and $15=3×5,$ then it is perforce divisible by $8$ and $3,$ and consequently, by $8×3$ as well.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Gotta be careful.  If we were told the integer were divisible by $8$ and by $12=4\times 3$ that would mean it is divisible by $8$ and $4$.  But that does not mean it is divisible by$8\times 4$.  (Because $8$ and $4$ aren't relatively prime.)

Comment: @fleablood I wouldn't argue that way since $4$ is already contained in the $8.$

Comment: @michaelrr Glad this helped you.

Comment: Exactly.  I'm pointing out that we need to avoid that error.

Comment: @fleablood Well, of course we do. But I don't think anyone who really understands what's happening (which is not so difficult to see) as opposed to blindly manipulating figures will *ever* fall into such bizzarre reasoning.

Comment: Well, yeah the OP asked.  It can't be obvious to everyone.

Comment: @fleablood OK, thanks for pointing it out, then.

Answer (score 3):

The prime numbers tell you everything here. The list of possible answers are relatively small so I’d begin by factoring each out: 
$$16 = 2^4$$ 
$$24 = 8 \cdot 3 = 2^3 \cdot 3$$
$$32 = 2^5$$
$$36 = 6^2 = 2^2 \cdot 3^2$$
$$45 = 3^2 \cdot 5.$$

Now, a number divisible by $8 = 2^3$ must have at least $3$ factors of $2$ and a number divisible by $15 = 3 \cdot 5$ must have at least one factor of $3$ and at least one factor of $5$.

Let’s now take a look at the list of possible answers. $16$ and $32$ won’t work since we only require $3$ factors of $2$. $36$ and $45$ won’t work because we require just one factor $3$. Hence the only remaining possibility among the list is $24$ (this case can be verified to be fine but I’d probably fill in $24$ and move on since it’s the GRE).

Answer (score 1):

We prove the following general result:

If

$p, q \in \Bbb P \tag 1$

are distinct primes and

$n \in \Bbb Z \tag 2$

with

$p^3 \mid n, \; q \mid n, \tag 3$

then

$p^3q \mid n; \tag 4$

for we have

$\gcd(p^3, q) = 1; \tag 5$

hence by Bezout's identity there exist $a, b \in \Bbb Z$ such that

$ap^3 + bq = 1; \tag 6$

we multiply this through by $n$:

$ap^3n + bqn = n; \tag 7$

we also have

$p^3 \mid n \Longrightarrow n = p^3x, \; x \in \Bbb Z, \tag 8$

$q \mid n \Longrightarrow n = qy, \; y \in \Bbb Z; \tag 9$

we substitute (8) and (9) into (7):

$ap^3qy + bqp^3x = n, \tag{10}$

whence

$p^3q(ay + bx) = n \Longrightarrow p^3q \mid n. \tag{11}$

Now taking

$p = 2, q = 3  \tag{12}$

yields the specific result that

$24 = 2^3 \cdot 3 \mid n. \tag{13}$

***Note Added in Edit, Wendesday 13 November 2019 9:50 AM PST:***  It is perhaps worth noting that our result here may easily be extended from the case $p^3 \mid n$ to the case $p^k \mid n$ for arbitrary $k \in \Bbb N$; indeed, one need merely walk through the above with $p^3$ replaced by $p^k$ to see that this is so.

It is also likely worth pointing out that

$\gcd(p, q) = 1 \Longrightarrow \gcd(p^k, q) = 1, \; \forall k \in \Bbb N; \tag{14}$

indeed, we may write

$ap + bq = 1, \; a, b \in \Bbb Z; \tag{15}$

focussing for the moment on the case $k = 2$ we multiply (15) through by $p$:

$ap^2 + bqp = p; \tag{16}$

then

$\gcd(p^2, q) = d > 1 \Longrightarrow d \mid p^2, \; d \mid q; \tag{17}$

by virtue of (16) this implies

$d \mid p \Rightarrow \Leftarrow \gcd(p, q) = 1; \tag{18}$

this contradiction forces

$\gcd(p^2, q) = 1; \tag{20}$

this logic may be extended to general $k \in \Bbb N$ by an inductive argument: if

$\gcd(p^k, q) = 1, \tag{21}$

we multiply (15) by $p^k$:

$ap^{k + 1} + bqp^k = p^k; \tag{22}$

now if

$\gcd(p^{k + 1}, q) = d > 1, \tag{23}$

as above we have

$d \mid p^{k + 1}, \; d \mid q \Longrightarrow d \mid p^k, \tag{24}$

which of course is precluded by (21); therefore

$\gcd(p, q) = 1 \Longrightarrow \gcd(p^k, q) = 1, \; \forall k \in \Bbb N. \tag{25}$

***End of Note.***

Comment: That is great, @robertlewis. I am really grateful that you put all the effort into this fine proof but I must admit it is a little over my head.

Comment: @michaelrr:  Thank you for the kind words.  I simply used standard facts and techniques from very basic number theory.  You might check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity.  Cheers!